# why error st.data is not a function in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using caching in jquery or using `data` function in jquery .I am generating dynamic list as well as adding a property in `data`.But I am getting error in while adding the property in data function.

https://jsfiddle.net/pn9p3szx/1/

```
$(function(){
var data =[{name:'test',o:{add:'nnnn'}},{name:'test2',o:{add:'nnnn'}},];
var arr=[];
var str ='<ul>';
arr.push(str)
$( data).each(function( index ,item) {
var st ='<li>'+item.name+'</li>';
st.data('o',item.o)
arr.push(st)
});
var s ='</ul>';
arr.push(s)
$('#test').append(arr)
$('#test').on('click', 'li', clickHand);
function clickHand(){
alert('---'+$(this).data('o'))
}
})
```

Comment: you have to use jQuery object `$(st).data('o',item.o)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting this error because `st` is not a jQuery object, but an HTML string. Change the line where you define `st` to this:

```
var st =$('<li>'+item.name+'</li>');
```

[Corrected JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pn9p3szx/2/).